# Sort the keys of a dictionary by key using a list and for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I need to sort this dictionary that counts the times that some words appear in a song:

```
word_freq = {'love': 25, 'conversation': 1, 'every': 6, "we're": 1, 'plate': 1, 'sour': 1, 'jukebox': 1, 'now': 11, 'taxi': 1, 'fast': 1, 'bag': 1, 'man': 1, 'push': 3, 'baby': 14, 'going': 1, 'you': 16, "don't": 2, 'one': 1, 'mind': 2, 'backseat': 1, 'friends': 1, 'then': 3, 'know': 2, 'take': 1, 'play': 1, 'okay': 1, 'so': 2, 'begin': 1, 'start': 2, 'over': 1, 'body': 17, 'boy': 2, 'just': 1, 'we': 7, 'are': 1, 'girl': 2, 'tell': 1, 'singing': 2, 'drinking': 1, 'put': 3, 'our': 1, 'where': 1, "i'll": 1, 'all': 1, "isn't": 1, 'make': 1, 'lover': 1, 'get': 1, 'radio': 1, 'give': 1, "i'm": 23, 'like': 10, 'can': 1, 'doing': 2, 'with': 22, 'club': 1, 'come': 37, 'it': 1, 'somebody': 2, 'handmade': 2, 'out': 1, 'new': 6, 'room': 3, 'chance': 1, 'follow': 6, 'in': 27, 'may': 2, 'brand': 6, 'that': 2, 'magnet': 3, 'up': 3, 'first': 1, 'and': 23, 'pull': 3, 'of': 6, 'table': 1, 'much': 2, 'last': 3, 'i': 6, 'thrifty': 1, 'grab': 2, 'was': 2, 'driver': 1, 'slow': 1, 'dance': 1, 'the': 18, 'say': 2, 'trust': 1, 'family': 1, 'week': 1, 'date': 1, 'me': 10, 'do': 3, 'waist': 2, 'smell': 3, 'day': 6, 'although': 3, 'your': 21, 'leave': 1, 'want': 2, "let's": 2, 'lead': 6, 'at': 1, 'hand': 1, 'how': 1, 'talk': 4, 'not': 2, 'eat': 1, 'falling': 3, 'about': 1, 'story': 1, 'sweet': 1, 'best': 1, 'crazy': 2, 'let': 1, 'too': 5, 'van': 1, 'shots': 1, 'go': 2, 'to': 2, 'a': 8, 'my': 33, 'is': 5, 'place': 1, 'find': 1, 'shape': 6, 'on': 40, 'kiss': 1, 'were': 3, 'night': 3, 'heart': 3, 'for': 3, 'discovering': 6, 'something': 6, 'be': 16, 'bedsheets': 3, 'fill': 2, 'hours': 2, 'stop': 1, 'bar': 1}
```

In order to do it I need:

1. To create a new list just with the keys of the dictionary.

```
keys = list(word_freq.keys())
```

2. Sort the key list.

```
keys.sort()
```

3. Create an empty dictionary.

```
word_freq2 = {}
```

4. Use a for loop lo iterate each value of the list. For each iterated, find the corresponding value in the first dictionary and insert the key-value pair to the new empty dictionary.

This is my best solution up to now:

```
for key in keys:
    if key in word_freq:
        word_freq2.update({key: value})

print(word_freq2)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add the correct value because right know I receive just 1 as a value, as I show here:

```
{'a': 1, 'about': 1, 'all': 1, 'although': 1, 'and': 1, 'are': 1, 'at': 1, 'baby': 1, 'backseat': 1, 'bag': 1, 'bar': 1, 'be': 1, 'bedsheets': 1, 'begin': 1, 'best': 1, 'body': 1, 'boy': 1, 'brand': 1, 'can': 1, 'chance': 1, 'club': 1, 'come': 1, 'conversation': 1, 'crazy': 1, 'dance': 1, 'date': 1, 'day': 1, 'discovering': 1, 'do': 1, 'doing': 1, "don't": 1, 'drinking': 1, 'driver': 1, 'eat': 1, 'every': 1, 'falling': 1, 'family': 1, 'fast': 1, 'fill': 1, 'find': 1, 'first': 1, 'follow': 1, 'for': 1, 'friends': 1, 'get': 1, 'girl': 1, 'give': 1, 'go': 1, 'going': 1, 'grab': 1, 'hand': 1, 'handmade': 1, 'heart': 1, 'hours': 1, 'how': 1, 'i': 1, "i'll": 1, "i'm": 1, 'in': 1, 'is': 1, "isn't": 1, 'it': 1, 'jukebox': 1, 'just': 1, 'kiss': 1, 'know': 1, 'last': 1, 'lead': 1, 'leave': 1, 'let': 1, "let's": 1, 'like': 1, 'love': 1, 'lover': 1, 'magnet': 1, 'make': 1, 'man': 1, 'may': 1, 'me': 1, 'mind': 1, 'much': 1, 'my': 1, 'new': 1, 'night': 1, 'not': 1, 'now': 1, 'of': 1, 'okay': 1, 'on': 1, 'one': 1, 'our': 1, 'out': 1, 'over': 1, 'place': 1, 'plate': 1, 'play': 1, 'pull': 1, 'push': 1, 'put': 1, 'radio': 1, 'room': 1, 'say': 1, 'shape': 1, 'shots': 1, 'singing': 1, 'slow': 1, 'smell': 1, 'so': 1, 'somebody': 1, 'something': 1, 'sour': 1, 'start': 1, 'stop': 1, 'story': 1, 'sweet': 1, 'table': 1, 'take': 1, 'talk': 1, 'taxi': 1, 'tell': 1, 'that': 1, 'the': 1, 'then': 1, 'thrifty': 1, 'to': 1, 'too': 1, 'trust': 1, 'up': 1, 'van': 1, 'waist': 1, 'want': 1, 'was': 1, 'we': 1, "we're": 1, 'week': 1, 'were': 1, 'where': 1, 'with': 1, 'you': 1, 'your': 1}
```

Comment: Each key is unique, so you have only 1 of it inside word_freq. Alsp the `if` is useless you check if the key is in the dict which is the origin of the list you iterate on, so YES every one will be in the dict

Comment: Do you just want to sort word_freq by key ?

Comment: @azro Yes, exactly.

Comment: Make sure you're using a version of Python for which insertion order is preserved.

Comment: What is the `value` in `{key:value}`? Did you mean: `word_freq2[key] = word_freq[key]`?

Comment: @quamrana yes, the keys are the same, but a I need the value from word_freq.

Comment: You don't assign anything to `value`. Did you get an error?

Comment: I would suggest to create a pandas dataframe from the dict and then simply sort that by the word count

Comment: @quamrana I dont get an error but I dont get the result that I want because all the values are 1 not the values from word_freq.

Comment: I get an error when I run your code.

Comment: You don't need an extra dict and all that useless stuff. `word_freq = {k: v for k, v in sorted(word_freq.items())}` is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work just fine:

```py
word_freq = {'love': 25, 'conversation': 1, 'every': 6, "we're": 1, 'plate': 1, 'sour': 1, 'jukebox': 1, 'now': 11, 'taxi': 1, 'fast': 1, 'bag': 1, 'man': 1, 'push': 3, 'baby': 14, 'going': 1, 'you': 16, "don't": 2, 'one': 1, 'mind': 2, 'backseat': 1, 'friends': 1, 'then': 3, 'know': 2, 'take': 1, 'play': 1, 'okay': 1, 'so': 2, 'begin': 1, 'start': 2, 'over': 1, 'body': 17, 'boy': 2, 'just': 1, 'we': 7, 'are': 1, 'girl': 2, 'tell': 1, 'singing': 2, 'drinking': 1, 'put': 3, 'our': 1, 'where': 1, "i'll": 1, 'all': 1, "isn't": 1, 'make': 1, 'lover': 1, 'get': 1, 'radio': 1, 'give': 1, "i'm": 23, 'like': 10, 'can': 1, 'doing': 2, 'with': 22, 'club': 1, 'come': 37, 'it': 1, 'somebody': 2, 'handmade': 2, 'out': 1, 'new': 6, 'room': 3, 'chance': 1, 'follow': 6, 'in': 27, 'may': 2, 'brand': 6, 'that': 2, 'magnet': 3, 'up': 3, 'first': 1, 'and': 23, 'pull': 3, 'of': 6, 'table': 1, 'much': 2, 'last': 3, 'i': 6, 'thrifty': 1, 'grab': 2, 'was': 2, 'driver': 1, 'slow': 1, 'dance': 1, 'the': 18, 'say': 2, 'trust': 1, 'family': 1, 'week': 1, 'date': 1, 'me': 10, 'do': 3, 'waist': 2, 'smell': 3, 'day': 6, 'although': 3, 'your': 21, 'leave': 1, 'want': 2, "let's": 2, 'lead': 6, 'at': 1, 'hand': 1, 'how': 1, 'talk': 4, 'not': 2, 'eat': 1, 'falling': 3, 'about': 1, 'story': 1, 'sweet': 1, 'best': 1, 'crazy': 2, 'let': 1, 'too': 5, 'van': 1, 'shots': 1, 'go': 2, 'to': 2, 'a': 8, 'my': 33, 'is': 5, 'place': 1, 'find': 1, 'shape': 6, 'on': 40, 'kiss': 1, 'were': 3, 'night': 3, 'heart': 3, 'for': 3, 'discovering': 6, 'something': 6, 'be': 16, 'bedsheets': 3, 'fill': 2, 'hours': 2, 'stop': 1, 'bar': 1}
keys = list(word_freq.keys())
keys.sort()
word_freq2 = {}
for key in keys:
    word_freq2[key] = word_freq[key]

print(word_freq2)
```

Comment: This is overcomplicated. `word_freq = {k: v for k, v in sorted(word_freq.items())}` is enough

Comment: I’m just taking one step further on than the OP, but with code that works.

Comment: You could improve that and teach each a so much easier way :)